# Search with multiple input and between two date does not work when the date textbox is empty

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

What I'm trying to do is I'm doing a quicksearch with multiple input so that if either any of the textbox is filled even when there are empty textbox, the data can still be retrieved.

The problem that I've faced is when I've tried to do the searching with date range the data failed to search when the date textbox of the date is empty.
Even when other textbox is not null.

I've also tried finding the date range using this method:

```
and (convert(varchar, DateIssue, 105) between @DateTo and @DateFrom  )
```

next is query that I used for searching

```
SELECT * FROM [Table2]

where  (ID like '%' + @ID  + '%' or ID=@ID   )

and(Pic_Mgr like '%' + @Picmgr + '%' or Pic_Mgr=@Picmgr) 


and(DEPT like '%' + @dept + '%' or DEPT=@dept)

 and ( DateIssue between @DateTo and @DateFrom )
```

next is the code behind that I used to get the parameter value:

```
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtid.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dept", txtIssDept.Text)


            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Picmgr", txtPICMgr.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo", txtdateto.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", txtdatefrm.Text)
```

I've tried to do the searching without the date range and it work just fine.So I assume there might be problem with my query regarding handling the datetime data .

Is there any suggestion on how to fix this ??

Comment: You'll have to test for null then. How about `and (@DateTo is null OR @DateFrom is null) or ( DateIssue between @DateTo and @DateFrom ))` . I don't know whether you want to allow open-ended dates though - e.g. maybe if only DateFrom is populated you'd change the criteria to `DateIssue >= @DateFrom` or something. I'll leave that up to you. But basically you can use `or` conditions to either add the criteria, or just do nothing if a parameter is null

Comment: Another option is that you use the .NET code to build up the SQL string gradually, and only append the date criteria to the string (and add the parameters to the command) if the fields are filled in. That might be better in terms of query performance.

Comment: P.S. A different point: `and(Pic_Mgr like '%' + @Picmgr + '%' or Pic_Mgr=@Picmgr)` is redundant. Just writing `and(Pic_Mgr like '%' + @Picmgr + '%')` will do the same job. If the parameter value is equal to the field value, then it will be matched by a LIKE (because that matches whether the paramter value is contained in the field - which of course it is, it's just that it's also the whole of the field). Same for `and(DEPT like '%' + @dept + '%' or DEPT=@dept)` - you can change it to `and(DEPT like '%' + @dept + '%')`

Comment: so I've  already test it for null. The data can't be retrieved whether both or one  of the date is null.

Comment: " I've already test it for null" ...where? Your code above doesn't do that.

Comment: I've tested it by setting the  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo", " ")
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", " ")

Comment: What use would that be? It's not going to match anything in the `DateIssue` field to a space character either. You'll end up executing something like `and (DateIssue between ' ' and ' ')`. Clearly that makes no sense. If either of the date fields are not filled in then you need to make sure that BETWEEN criteria does not get executed. Which is what I was trying to explain in my first two comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM [Table2]
where  (ID like '%' + @ID  + '%' or ID=@ID   )
and(Pic_Mgr like '%' + @Picmgr + '%' or Pic_Mgr=@Picmgr) 
and(DEPT like '%' + @dept + '%' or DEPT=@dept)
 and (DateIssue between
 (case when isnull(@DateTo,'') <>'' then @DateTo else DateIssue end) and
 (case when isnull(@DateFrom,'') <>'' then @DateFrom else DateIssue end))
```

Comment: it might work but to make a good quality answer you also need to add some explanation of what you have changed, and why

Comment: Also read my comments above to see that some other parts of the query are redundant. A good answer would also point out other problems in the code, if they're not too complicated to discuss.

Comment: Here, I have made a change in the where condition. you can use the case statement for checking the null from date and to date.

Comment: You should write the explanation in the actual answer, not the comments.